# MVC 3 Returning a count of 0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Store/

   ProductsStoreEntities storeDB = new ProductsStoreEntities();
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var items = storeDB.item.ToList();
       return PartialView(items);
   }
```

**Index View**

```
model IEnumerable<MvcProductsStore.Models.Item>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Store";
}

<h3>Browse Products:</h3>


<p>
    Select from @Model.Count()
    Products:
</p>

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.IName,"Browse", new { item = item.IName })</li>
    }
</ul>
```

**Sample Data**

```
namespace MvcProductsStore.Models
{
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProductsStoreEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ProductsStoreEntities context)
        {
            var items = new List<Item>
             {
                 new Item {ItemId = 1000, IName = "Patches"},
                 new Item {ItemId = 2000,IName = "Jewelry"},
                 new Item {ItemId = 3000, IName = "Wood Working"}   
             };
             items.ForEach(s => context.item.Add(s));
        }
    }
```

**Models**

```
namespace MvcProductsStore.Models
{
    public class ProductsStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> item { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

Not really returning an error, but when I click on store it tells me to Select from 0 items.  So instead of picking up the list of items it getting a count of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You have not saved your database context object after the seed method 
So you should add

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

in the Sample Data portion, the Seed Method

Answer (score 0):

please change return View() instead of PartialView().

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Store/

   ProductsStoreEntities storeDB = new ProductsStoreEntities();
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var items = storeDB.item.ToList();
       return View(items);
   }
```

Comment: Add the save message and change return PartialView to return view is there anything else I'm missing still giving me Select from 0 items.